# Why Android SDK path has to set in Qt Android device?

Tags: android, qt

I am little bit confused with SDK path in qt for mobile. I know Qt is based on Android NDK (C++). Then why we need to set path of SDK in tools->options->device->android->sdk path. Is SDK is based on Java?

Answer (score 1):

NDK is used to compile your C++ code.
But NDK is only able to generate .so files (libraries compiled from C++). SDK is needed to generate the apk that will contain the program's main entry point that will end up using the .so files compiled by the NDK.

I don't think (not sure) that any app can be deployed on an Android device without using the SDK. Anyway, even if that could be possible, the way QtCreator works, it needs the SDK to deploy your application correctly on the device.